# error when get string from aggreagate result

Tags: apex, query, aggregateresult

can u help me fix this error?

> error message : System.SObjectException: Invalid field
>   Element_Name__r.Name for AggregateResult

here my code

```
AggregateResult[] VFLDLSTGroupElm = [SELECT Employee_No__c, Element_Name__r.Name FROM PYEMPELEMENT__c WHERE Period__c = 'a0t41000000QiUzAAK' GROUP BY Element_Name__r.Name, Employee_No__c];
for(AggregateResult VFLDLSTGroupElmLoops : VFLDLSTGroupElm)
{
String VLDGetEmpNo = String.valueof(VFLDLSTGroupElmLoops.get('Employee_No__c'));
String VLDGetElmName = String.valueof(VFLDLSTGroupElmLoops.get('Element_Name__r.Name')) ;

//System.debug('No :'+VLDGetEmpNo + 'Name :'+ VLDGetElmName);
//System.debug('No :'+VLDGetEmpNo );
System.debug('Name :'+ VLDGetElmName );
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access it like

```
VFLDLSTGroupElmLoops.getSobject('Element_Name__r').get('Name');
```

You need to traverse it in parent you can't directly access it.